# K-dimensional equidistribution - how big are periods of PCG?

Tags: pseudo-random-generator

I'm trying to figure out what is period of PCG generator XSL-RR-RR:

https://www.pcg-random.org

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permuted_congruential_generator

If we use just random multiplier and increment in LCG in that PCG. M. O'Neill wrote:

"For the PCG family, arbitrary k-dimensional equidistribution (and the huge periods it implies) requires PCG's extended generation scheme."

It looks like their generators has big periods, XSL-RR-RR too. But I can't find accurate information about that. She proved somehow that they are k-dimensional equidistributed. But what is k exactly, what periods it implies and could it be the same with every parameter of LCG in XSL-RR-RR? She tested some specific multiplier and increments so maybe other ones have worse parameters and periods?

I don't understand exactly why she use just some specific miltipliers (two ones if I understand it well) and increments in XSL-RR-RR. What will happen if we will use other, random ones?

Comment: LCGs are fun to be sure. But is there something deeper that you're thinking about? Is there an ultimate objective, especially related to security (this is the crypto forum after all)? Some here can help.

Comment: In this case it is rather math problem, but people here know well such topics, so I thought someone can give me answear. If they all have a big periods it implies that we can built quite fine cipher with just some number of keyed LCGs in PCG, one by one. PCG with specific keyed LCG could be just one round of the cipher and if it has big period and other parameters, as with multipliers proposed by M. O'Neill - it will be strong (keyed) PRF. So that's my motivation.

Comment: I wrote about PCG, not LCG. Anyway cipher is different story. Now I have to decide what is period of PCG with random LCG mod 2^128 and what are properties of such generators (do they also pass randomness tests).

Answer (score 1):

PCG is just LCG where the output is run through a transformation. The amount of internal state of the PCG - which is what controls the period - is all contained in the underlying LCG. So the period is $2^n$ where $n$ is the number of bits of state. The only thing to worry about is if the output transformation makes the period smaller, but since it's a permutation it does not.

When pcg-random.com talks about "arbitrary" period, they just mean that they have a way to make the internal state arbitrarily large. For a given state size, the period is the same as other algorithms of the same size.

Comment: Thus to achieve period 2^128 we can use Hull–Dobell Theorem, which guarantee full period in LCG mod 2^n. So PCG mixer itself does not change the period length, right? By the way note that XSL-RR-RR transform 128-bit input into 128-bit output. I find it not obvious to prove, that period of PCG will be the same as in LCG, which we used in that PCG (XSL-RR-RR). How do you know that? I suspect that it's true for every permutation on which we act with some mixer. But, for example, permutation composition is also kind of mixer and it won't preserves cycles.

Comment: What is expected cycle length in random 128-bit LCG? Is is the same as in uniform random permutation, where expected cycle length is about 2^127?

Comment: The periods of LCG are well-studied, see the Wikipedia article for details.

Comment: Something is wrong here. If we consider LCG + simple mixer it is not always true that expected period of such generator will be the same. Let's reverse block after every step in our mixer. It looks like LCG + reverse gives different expected period (I can't proof it, but it looks like this). So how do we know that something changing the permutation in such a complicated way like XSL-RR-RR will give us the same period as underlying LCG. And by the period I understand expected cycle length (maybe I undesrtand it wrong?).

Comment: Your WP link claims XSL-RR-RR is invertible, therefore a permutation, therefore the period is the same as the LCG. I'm not sure what you mean by "reverse", but if it's invertible it won't affect the period.

Comment: Consider LCG x=x*3 mod 16. We have there 2 cycles with period 4, 2 cycles with period 2 and 4 cycles with period 1. Now consider the same LCG with mixer, which do rotr by 1 bit. So for example 1101 became 1110. Now we got one cycle with period 7, 2 cycles with period 4 and 1 cycle with period 1. In first case we got average period 2 and in second case we got average period 4. This simple mixer on output have changed expected period. How do you know that something more complicated that just rotr by one bit will not change expected period?

Comment: What's more, expected cycle length in random permutation of $n$ elements is:

$\frac{1}{2}(n+1)$

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_permutation_statistics#Expected_number_of_cycles_of_a_given_size_m

If PCG mixer makes LCG more random (so much, that it pass most tests) it could extend expected cycle lenght of typical underlying LCG (they have rather shorter expected periods) and make it closer to expected cycle length in random permutation. Isn't it? More random pemutation - longer expected period?

Comment: I haven't gone through your example, but you definitely can't get a longer cycle. The permutation is just for output, you aren't using it to update x, are you?

Comment: I'm computing 3*3 mod 16 = 9, 3*9 mod 16 = 11, 3*11 mod 16 = 1, 3*1 mod 16 = 3. So I have a cycle 3,9,11,1. And this is without any mixer on output. If we invent some mixer, even very simple, it will be different cycle.

Comment: No, it won't. For any output transform f, the output sequence will be f(3), f(9), f(11), f(1).

Comment: So let's do rotr by 1 bit as an output mixer. rotr(x=3*3 mod 16) = rotr(1001) = 1100 = 12. rotr(12*3 mod 16) = rotr(0100) = 0010 = 2. rotr(2*3 mod 16) = rotr(0110) = 0011 = 3. This is different cycle 3,12,2.

Comment: The Wikipedia article is clear that the transform is used to produce output from the state and does not also update the state.

Comment: Ok, so I want to investigate what will happen if we update the state. And that's what I'm talking about from the beginning, if we don't have another misunderstanding here. And that's not a trivial question, isn't it?